# What Roles and Features are installed by default on Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Is there somewhere that I can get a list of the default Roles and Features that are installed on a Windows Server 2012 R2 server?

Comment: Running `Get-WindowsFeature |Where { $_.Installed }` in the powershell right after the installation will show all installed roles and features.

Comment: How is this information useful? You'd anyway add the roles and features you need while configuring the server.

Comment: I am looking for a complete list of Roles and Features that are installed by default on a Windows Server 2012 R2 server. I don't have a clean install to run that command. Thank you.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2012-r2

Answer (score 1):

On Azure, my default Windows 2012R2 virtual machines have these features enabled by default:

```
PS > Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object { $_.Installed } | Format-Table -AutoSize

Display Name                                          Name                      Install State
------------                                          ----                      -------------
[X] File and Storage Services                         FileAndStorage-Services       Installed
    [X] Storage Services                              Storage-Services              Installed
[X] .NET Framework 4.5 Features                       NET-Framework-45-Features     Installed
    [X] .NET Framework 4.5                            NET-Framework-45-Core         Installed
    [X] WCF Services                                  NET-WCF-Services45            Installed
        [X] TCP Port Sharing                          NET-WCF-TCP-PortSharing45     Installed
[X] BitLocker Drive Encryption                        BitLocker                     Installed
[X] Enhanced Storage                                  EnhancedStorage               Installed
[X] User Interfaces and Infrastructure                User-Interfaces-Infra         Installed
    [X] Graphical Management Tools and Infrastructure Server-Gui-Mgmt-Infra         Installed
    [X] Server Graphical Shell                        Server-Gui-Shell              Installed
[X] Windows PowerShell                                PowerShellRoot                Installed
    [X] Windows PowerShell 4.0                        PowerShell                    Installed
    [X] Windows PowerShell ISE                        PowerShell-ISE                Installed
[X] WoW64 Support                                     WoW64-Support                 Installed
```

Answer (score -1):

According to Microsoft, "The File and Storage Services role and the Storage Services role service are installed by default, but without any additional role services."

source: [File and Storage Services Overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh831487(v=ws.11))